# What's the difference between OSGi and Java Service Provider Interface?

Tags: java, osgi

What is the difference between OSGi and Java SPI? what are the pros and cons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java SPI is mainly meant for providing implementations of Java standards. This approach gives some decoupling between clients and providers of the services. The implementing classes are defined in META-INF/services.
It is a very simple model though. An implementation can not be injected with other services and there also is no configuration model. So this mainly works for low level services that have no other dependencies.

OSGi also supports decoupling of clients and providers of services. It also allows configuration and dynamic registration of services. Also there are several programming models like declarative services and CDI which can interoperate.

The downside of OSGi is that it requires all libraries to live in a modular classloader and cope with dynamic loading and unloading of jars (bundles). As not all libraries are built like this there is a limited set of java libraries that actually work well inside of OSGi.

Comment: Is it possible to migrate from osgi to java spi in enterprise level applications? and is there any easy way to do it?

Comment: As I described spi is not meant for applications. It will not be able to replace OSGi code. What you can look into is CDI (for example Quarkus) or Spring.

Comment: Java SPI is the mechanism to load some Java Standard implementations. It is not meant for application developers at all.
So to create any useful bigger application you likely will want a dependency injection framework like one of the alternatives I listed. The alternatives to OSGi do not support the same level of modularity but in many cases this level of modularity is not needed.

Comment: " An implementation can not be injected with other services and there also is no configuration model. So this mainly works for low level services that have no other dependencies" but the configuration file is the file mentioned in the META-INF/services and we can inject a SPI using service loader in another SPI

Comment: "So to create any useful bigger application you likely will want a dependency injection framework like one of the alternatives I listed" but Java SPI providing a dependency injection 1)Metadata Registries (Service Implementations Space/Container) , 2) ServiceLoader as Injector . so what's wrong with java SPI?

Comment: Try it if you want. You will quickly see it sucks for applications.